# How to add my own PRAGMA statements in SQLite to store custom meta data

Tags: sql, sqlite, metadata, pragma

I want to store meta data like author name, copyright, source to my SQLite DB without creating a new table. I found out we can use PRAGMA statements to set some values.. I would like to store my own custom name and value ... How to create custom PRAGMA statement? http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

Has anyone done this before?  The doc says..

"The C-language API for SQLite provides the SQLITE_FCNTL_PRAGMA file control which gives VFS implementations the opportunity to add new PRAGMA statements or to override the meaning of built-in PRAGMA statements."

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that is not the intent of PRAGMA statements.  why do you not want to store the data in a table?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in PRAGMAs that store their value in the database do so in the [database header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).

There is not enough space to add custom values.

You have no choice but to create a new table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is enough for you, but I use `user_version` to keep track of the last schema check.

What I do is save the timestamp it was last checked against the code schema. If it's been 24h, or 5m, or whatever, I do a re-check and update stuff. I only need 1 32b int for that, so it's perfect. If you need more, this is not it.

More info on `user_version` [here (`PRAGMA schema_version`)](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) and [here (db reserved header space)](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header)

Comment: Have you considered the 2038 problem?

Comment: Nope. I save current timestamps ('last update'). I don't make software for 20y into the future. We'll have something else then, like SQLite 5.

Comment: Famous last words :)

Comment: That's what people said in 1980, right? =) And then suddenly came 1999. Noooooooooo. Eh, we'll see =)

Comment: Exactly. Let's hope SQLite v4 changes `user_version` to a signed _64_-bit int :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new [Checksum VFS Shim](https://www.sqlite.org/cksumvfs.html) for an example of a VFS adding a custom pragma.

The source code is linked on the page above, but [here is it again](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/cksumvfs.c), just in case.

But of course, you cannot store additional information, except via tables.
So while the above does show how to implement a custom pragma, your actual
end-goal is not possible, since the header is fixed and reserved for SQLite itself. If you have a table, why have a pragma then?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [ddevienne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103724/ddevienne) about looking at the [VFS Shim sources](https://www.sqlite.org/cksumvfs.html) is the step in the right direction, but the comment about impossibility to store your own data is partially correct (I could not add a comment due to my early insufficient reputation so posting as an answer). It's your own vfs so you're free to organize the data as you wish. xRead and xWrite [interfaces](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html) just assumes the sqlite own positional logic, but you can reserve an area at the start of the file for your own purposes and translate the positions accordingly. I can confirm this works since implemented an vfs reserving a small area at the start using this technique. But there are consequences, in this case the file won't be compatible with conventional sqlite tools and libraries.